# Forward networkinterface trafic on docker container

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I am working with this docker compose file: https://github.com/akvorado/akvorado/blob/main/docker-compose.yml

The containers are running on a machine that receive UDP traffic on a specific interface on a specific port.
Interface name: ens2f0np0
Interface IP: 192.168.255.27
Port: 2055
I have checked that I get traffic using a tcmpdump -i ens2f0np0

Now I want to foward this traffic to my docker service named inlet:
https://github.com/akvorado/akvorado/blob/main/docker-compose.yml#L96

The container bind port 2055 but as it not the same network nothing is seen.

I tried to change port: 192.168.255.27:2055:2055/udp but I change nothing I am guessing it is because this is not the same network (docker network vs host network).

How can I forward the traffic ?

Thx